# Jmeter Extracting null values in jmeter json extractor

Tags: json, jmeter

I am using jmeter json extractor
My JSON response looks as below -

```
{ "data": 
    [ 
    { 
    ".auths": 
    [ 
    { 
    "asf": 
    { 
    "__t": "aaaaa", 
    "vs": 1, 
    "v": 
    [ { 
    "__id": "1", 
    ".state": 1, 
    ".version": 275, 
    "authorizedSubFlight": { "v": "SUB1" }, 
    "purchaseOrderNumber": 
    { "__t": "0000", "vs": 1, "v": "9999", "vl": "PO1" } }, 
    { 
    "__t": "bbbbb", 
    "vs": 1, 
    "v": [ 
    { 
    "__id": "2", 
    ".state": 1, 
    ".version": 275, 
    "authorizedSubFlight": { "v": "SUB2" }, 
    "purchaseOrderNumber": 
    { "__t": "0000", "vs": 1, "v": null, } }, 
    { 
    "__t": "ccccc", 
    "vs": 1, 
    "v": [ 
    { 
    "__id": "3", 
    ".state": 1, 
    ".version": 275, 
    "authorizedSubFlight": { "v": "SUB3" }, 
    "purchaseOrderNumber": null },
```

& so on...

I need to extract the values of **authorizedSubFlight** & **purchaseOrderNumber** as below -

```
var_sb_1 = SUB1, var_po_1 = PO1
var_sb_2 = SUB2, var_po_2 = NULL
var_sb_3 = SUB3, var_po_3 = NULL
```

I am then using these value in **jdbc request** which is under a while loop for each value of `var_sb`, so I would want that for `SUB1`, `var_po` should read always read  the first value `var_po_1` which is PO1 etc.
My problem is specifically with extracting `var_po` values. I am using JSON extractor as -

```
json path expression: $..data[*].[".auths"][*].purchaseOrderNumber.vl 
match no: -1 
default value: null
```

I am expecting `var_po_2 = null` & `var_po_3 = null`, but all I am getting is `var_po = null` & hence my further checks are failing.

This might be because I am extracting value of vl in the json path expression & I do not have vl for second & thrid case.

Is there a way to handle such a case in json extractor ?

Comment: unless you pasted it wrong, this json **is** invalid: first of all, `{ "__t": "0000", "vs": 1, "v": 9999 "vl": PO1 }` (missing comma, and `PO1` shoudl be in quotes); second, it doesn't close properly

Comment: Updated the json.